# I got an warning while returning an NSInteger

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I have an warning while returning an NSInteger. I am using UITableView's inbuilt method numberOfRowsInSection. When i am returning it, It gives me an warning which is (Incompatible integer to pointer conversation returning 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')from a function with result type 'NSInteger *'(aka 'int *')).

I am using this code.

```
-(NSInteger *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSInteger row=10;
return row;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler's right! Your method returns a pointer to an `NSInteger`. This is the signature you want:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table // << 'NSInteger', not 'NSInteger *'
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
…
```

`NSInteger` is not an objc object, it's an `int` or a `long`.

Comment: @Justin...so should i write -(NSInteger *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger *)section
{ }??

Comment: @Akash no - I've updated and clarified my answer. use the signature seen in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

this method should return an NSInteger, not an NSInteger* (pointer to an NSInteger)

You just need to fix the return type:

`-(NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {...}`

Answer (score -1):

you can directly return like this

```
 -(NSInteger *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return 10;
 }
```

OR

Store the Values in an array and return Count of that Array.